# WPF double sorting in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have custom sorting for IP column with reset. And I have reseting for other columns

[image]

```
public static void SortHandler(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {            
        DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        string sortPropertyName = Helpers.GetSortMemberPath(e.Column);           

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortPropertyName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sortPropertyName);
            if (sortPropertyName == "Ip")
            {   
                IComparer comparer = null;                   
                e.Handled = true;         

                if (e.Column.SortDirection.HasValue && e.Column.SortDirection.Value == ListSortDirection.Descending)
                {
                    e.Column.SortDirection = null;                        
                }
                else
                {
                    ListSortDirection direction = (e.Column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;                        
                    e.Column.SortDirection = direction;
                    comparer = new SortIPAddress(direction);
                }                    
                ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);                   
                lcv.CustomSort = comparer;
            }                
            // sorting is cleared when the previous state is Descending
            if (e.Column.SortDirection.HasValue && e.Column.SortDirection.Value == ListSortDirection.Descending)
            {                    
                int index = Helpers.FindSortDescription(dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions, sortPropertyName);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    e.Column.SortDirection = null;                       
                    dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.RemoveAt(index);
                    dataGrid.Items.Refresh();

                    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) != ModifierKeys.Shift)
                    {                            
                        dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
                        dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
                    }

                    // stop the default sort
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }             
    }
```

But if I do double sorting with `shift`, sorting for IP column resets.How to fix double sorting? 
Forum ask for more details, but I do not know what else to add

Answer (score 1):

Could you modify your code to add the sorting groups like so

```
DataG.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("col1", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
DataG.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("col2", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

which would apply sorting as you described.

Comment: It sorts only when app run. I want to  use header table for sorting. I have 15 columns

Answer (score 0):

If your data is coming from a collection of some class type, add a custom property that is combination of multiple fields...

```
public class YourClassType
{
   public string SomeColumn {get; set;}
   public int SomeInt {get; set; }
   ...

   public string SortCombination { get { return SomeColumn + SomeSort; }}
}
```

Then in the xaml data grid column, set the "SortMemberPath" to that property name.  Ex:

SortMemberPath = "SortCombination";

No extra "helper" to sort / double-sort... it uses the one column as the sort basis.  You could even format the number to be sure properly justified same length depending on its content.

Comment: But I need "helper" because some columns sort not right. And I need to reset sorting sometimes

Comment: @ДмитрийСуворов, you can just create additional properties based on those multiple fields such as IpTime, IpName, IpMac, MacName, etc and just have those combination fields and have your "sortMemberPath" of each column point to whichever field is wanted... unless you are trying to sort multiple ways in the same SINGLE column (aside from just ascending/descending), but how would you handle that... right-click menu option?  I use it regularly for compound field sorts.

Comment: I'm trying to do it

Comment: @ДмитрийСуворов, just checking to see if it finally did work for you via the adding of parts for the sort...